# Automatic Backup Not working -Orient Db

Tags: orientdb

I Have enable automatic backup by xml file(`orientdb-server-plugin.xml`)

it as follows.

```
<handler class="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.handler.OAutomaticBackup">            <parameters>
                <parameter value="true" name="enabled"/>
                <parameter value="4h" name="delay"/>
                <parameter value="23:00:00" name="firstTime"/>
                <parameter value="backup" name="target.directory"/>
                <parameter value="${DBNAME}-${DATE:yyyyMMddHHmmss}.zip" name="target.fileName"/>
                <parameter value="9" name="compressionLevel"/>
                <parameter value="1048576" name="bufferSize"/>
                <parameter value="" name="db.include"/>
                <parameter value="" name="db.exclude"/>
            </parameters>
        </handler>
```

But backup not working for me.
Please assist me to do this.

Comment: What version of OrientDb are you using ?

Comment: version 2.1.4

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should put the configuration into `orientdb-server-config.xml` file (Reference: [Automatic Backup Server Plugin](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Automatic-Backup.html)).
What OS are you using? You can also put absolute path of the backup folder in the `target.directory` parameter, just to be sure of location where backups will be stored. Check you logs, there should be a line saying:
`Automatic backup plugin installed and active: ...`
If not, please post your logs here for further investigation.

Thanks.

Hope it helps.